# Remove layer switcher controller in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have created a map in leaflet and added an overlay as:

```
map.layerscontrol.addOverlay(tile_layer,"{{ resource.title }}");
map.addLayer(tile_layer);
```

The map shows great and the layer as well.
Now I want to remove the 'layer switcher' controller.
How can I do that in Leaflet?

Comment: just remove 'map.layerscontrol();'

Comment: Even if I remove the first line of the code, the layer.control is still there displaying the base layers. How can I remove it completely?

Comment: What version of Leaflet are you using? How do you instantiate the `map`? It does not seem to me that you should have a Layers Control by default, nor that `map.layerscontrol` would be assigned without explicitly creating such a control.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I use a specific app of django for leaflet (django-leaflet) which automates the creation of this controler. But the question is how I can later remove the controller through js.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that already `removeFrom()` was renamed to `remove()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All controls in Leaflet should inherit the [`removeFrom` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-removefrom), so to remove your existing `layerscontrol`, you can use:

```
map.layerscontrol.removeFrom(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of leaflet do not add a `L.Control.Layers` to the map by default. I suggest you check if you're using a recent version, and check if you are manually adding a layers control somewhere.